# Oracle regexp_instr

Tags: regex, oracle

Can one maybe help me with a regular expression?

I wanted to check if in a given string the ',' is present or not.

literal: First_Name+;Last_Name+John, Smith

Here I wanted to check if Last_Name contains an ','

```
select case when regexp_instr('First_Name+;Last_Name+John, Smith;Home_Adress+Michigan',
                                       '^(.*?\;|\+)*Last_Name\+(.*\,).*$', ',') > 1

 then 'ok' else 'nok' end as test1 from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

The third argument to regexp_instr() is an optional starting position - just omit it.

Also, since your regexp matches the entire string, it doesn't make sense to check for regexp_instr() > 1 - if you get a match, regexp_instr() will return 1, otherwise 0.

```
with v_data as (
  select 'First_Name+;Last_Name+John, Smith;Home_Adress+Michigan' as name from dual 
  union all
  select 'First_Name+John;Last_Name+Smith;Home_Adress+Michigan' as name from dual 
)
select 
  name, 
  regexp_instr(name, '^(.*?\;|\+)*Last_Name\+(.*\,).*$') 
from v_data
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this solves your problem, please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: Test your regexp on string `First_Name+John;Last_Name+Smith;Home_Adress+Michigan,foo,bar`

Comment: @Egor I used the OP's regex without modification, but you're right - it wrongly matches any string that contains the comma after Last_Name+ .

Answer (score 0):

Why using regexp here?

```
case when 
    regexp_like(
      'First_Name+;Last_Name+John, Smith;Home_Adress+Michigan', 
      '(^|;)Last_Name\+[^;]*,'
    )
  then 'present' 
  else 'not present' 
end
```

Comment: user1814129 wants to check if *Last_Name* contains a comma, not the whole string.